# collectionfs insert userid for insert method

Tags: meteor

The default collectionfs insert function will add some images info to mongodb cfs.images.filerecord collection, how can I add my userId together with the insert method so whenever I need I could find images by userId?

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To acces the userId of the current in Meteor you can use

```
 Meteor.users.findOne({})._id
```

You can insert this in your collection for example through

```
Images.insert(
        {
           user: Meteor.users.findOne({})._id
           Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj)

        }
    )
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `Meteor.users.findOne({})._id` will return the id of the user being logged id. Use `Meteor.userId()` instead, which will guarantee this. http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_userid Furthermore, your second value in the object got no key?

Comment: this is a valid syntax?

Comment: @maxli No, a comma, parts of the function and a closing parenthesis is also missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, works but not sure if is the best solution:

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        // update the db since I know the file _id
        Images.update({_id:fileObj._id}, {$push:{user:Meteor.userId()}})
    });
});
```